# JavaScript removes element

Tags: javascript, html

here is a snippet of my .html file

```
<ul>
    <li>test entry1</li>
    <li>test entry2</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <br />
    &nbsp;
</ul>
```

and i want to remove the empty `<li></li>` tags.

And here a snippet of my JavaScript file.

```
var rules =
        {
            elements: 
            {

            li: function(element)
            {
                if(isEmpty)
                {
                    element.remove();
                }
            }
        }


function isEmpty(element)
{
    return element.childNodes.length === 0  && element.html().trim() === "";        
}
```

now my problem is, it looks like the function `isEmpty` returns every time `ture` so removes every list entry and not only the empty ones.

kind regards

Comment: You're not actually calling the `isEmpty` function - you need to add `()` `if (isEmpty(element))` - `isEmpty` just returns the function definition, which is truthy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774193/making-an-html-button-dissapear-when-clicked-through-javascript/46774243#46774243

Comment: What @tymeJV said, but you can have a comment as a childNode or a textNode that contains only whitespace could be a childNode so you're (probably) better off doing `return !element.textContent.trim()`

Comment: It's also worth noting that your HTML is invalid; the only valid child element of a `<ul>` is an `<li>` element (or, in HTML 4.1, a descendant `<ul>` or `<ol>`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my little contribution. This code works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul>
    <li>test entry1</li>
    <li>test entry2</li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <br />
    &nbsp;
</ul>

<script>
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for( i = 0 ; i<elements.length ; i++) {
    if(isEmpty(elements[i])){
        elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
        };
    };

function isEmpty(element)
{
    return !element.textContent.trim();        
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```